# Where do I find resources and information on ActiveRecord optimization?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Recently I started working on a huge Rails 3.1 project that contains several SQL queries per controller action and uses the AR query DSL extensively and deliberately. Many of these queries are composed of nested where, join and merge clauses. Of course this all makes the app really slow at some parts and I wanna know which resources, books, blogs are there to help Railers deal with it?

I appreciate any recommendation on any relevant source.

Thank you.

Comment: ActiveRecord is building queries in predefined way - there is nothing to optimize. You should just start grabbing the queries it generates and run explain on them with further optimization to make them all run within a fraction of a second. Then your all your AR will be "flying".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [The Ruby Reflector / SQL](http://rubyreflector.com/SQL) ., btw take a look at this [source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-rails3/).